# Swift - Variable scope with loading external data

Tags: ios, swift, scope, mapbox

I am using the Mapbox framework. I have used their Studio (web app) to create some map shapes (polygons and coordinates) that I have downloaded as a GeoJSON file. This file is bundled with my iOS app. All provided examples are very small and have a simple structure, like within `viewDidLoad` will all the remaining code.

I am trying to design the app so that the data is loaded once, and then this variable will be accessible to be able to add and / or remove some of these mapping items as needed.

Should I use a global variable? If so, where should I declare the `data` variable, so it can be accessed anywhere? Or is this bad practice, and I should load the `data` variable once somewhere with less scope access and pass the object itself around within appropriate function calls? Does this not also get confusing? Where would the best location be for the initial `data` load, `viewDidLoad()`?

```
do {
       let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "features", ofType: "geojson")!)
       let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
} catch {
       print(error)
}
```

Then I will have other functions that can then filter this data set, and only add or remove specific map objects.

```
func loadSomeData(forGroup name: String, withData data: Data) {
     let shapeCollection = try MGLShape(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! MGLShapeCollectionFeature
     for shape in shapeCollection.shapes {
          if shape.attribute(forKey: "group") as! String == name {
               if let point = shape as? MGLPointAnnotation {
                    // ADD ITEM TO MAP
               } else if let polygon = shape as? MGLPolygon {
                    // ADD ITEM TO MAP
               }
          }
     }
}

var group = "group1"
loadSomeData(forGroup: group)
```

So this would filter the same original data source for all objects with a property of "group1" and only load those (it will be preceeded by removing existing objects, and may do many other things - I just need to grasp the basics...)

Ultimately, I would prefer to parse the GeoJSON data file, and create custom objects for grouped items. But the file's structure is totally random and means the object class' properties would need to be entirely optionals, but some are lazy loaded / computed properties which don't work well with optionals, from my early testing...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a couple of issues: Loading data from your bundle, and making it globally accessible.

If the data will never change then simply reading it from your bundle should be fine. If it might change during the life of your app, you might want to write code that's run at launch that will check for the file in documents at launch, and copy it from the bundle to the documents directory if it's not found, then open it from documents.

Then you'd need to query your server to see if your data is current (using a version number or update timestamp.) If it's changed, you'd download the new data, save the changes to documents, and also update the version/timestamp.

As to making your data available app-wide, this might be a good use case for a data container singleton. The singleton would have methods to query your map data, and it would be responsible for the loading/updating logic I described above.

Alternately you might decide that the data would map well to Core Data.

As to how to design your data model, that's a separate conversation and you'd need to provide more information.

Comment: The data is for mapping data of different golf courses. Each course will have a data file, which would only infrequently change over time, so I'm not too bothered about that and would implement a versioning property or similar. I have just tried my sample code, but the `data` var is only accessible within the `do { } catch { }` block, so I can't use that either!

Comment: Never heard / read about "data container singletons" - swift newbie. I will have a search...

Comment: From what I am reading, Singleton's are viewed as a simpler solution, but maybe not preferred. "Dependency Injection" seems more preferred, but I can't seem to make the above code work in this contruct. I put a `CourseData` struct into CourseData.swift, and a `ModelController` class in ModelController.swift. When I try to instantiate a CourseData instance in the ModelController, it does not auto-fill the init parameters of the Struct. What have I got wrong?